# How to use Gravity Form to validate customer's information from .csv

Tags: wordpress, csv, gravity-forms-plugin

I am trying to use Gravity Forms to make a payment page in WordPress. The first three fields are customers name, order number and postcode and the last one is eway payment. I want to check the customer's name, order number and postcode through an Excel form before make payment. If the validation is successful, the last section will be active. Are there any add_ons or do I need to change the code? I actually have the code but I do not know where to put it. Thanks.

Comment: you can just add the code where you wrote the question. select it and click on code (format option)

Comment: Where I can add the code because there are lot of php files in Gravity Forms folder. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gravity Forms does have a couple of hooks you can use in your [theme functions file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Functions_File) or a [custom functionality plugin](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/02/02/creating-a-custom-functions-plugin-for-end-users) to perform your own validation.

The [gform_field_validation](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_field_validation/) filter can be used to perform custom validation of a specific field.

The [gform_validation](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_validation/) filter can be used to validate the entire form.

Comment: Hi richardW8k, thanks for your response. I have put the code in  the functions.php file of my active theme and it works. Thank you for your help. Cheers.